# PyAutoGUI - No Such File or Directory Error

Tags: pyautogui

Anyone have any luck on this ? I am tyring to recreate this `[tutorial code][1]` :

```
>>> import pyautogui
>>> button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc7key.png')
>>> button7location
(1416, 562, 50, 41)
>>> button7x, button7y = pyautogui.center(button7location)
>>> button7x, button7y
(1441, 582)
>>> pyautogui.click(button7x, button7y)
```

But I get the following error [at line 2 of the code above] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'calc7key.PNG' when I have such file stored in  File "C:\Users*******\Desktop\Python\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze__init__.py", line 165, in _locateAll_python
    **needleFileObj = open(needleImage, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'calc7key.PNG'** ..anyone have any luck using this. essentially I am trying to screenshot a minimized tab to be opened by pyautogui (like lets say the google chrome icon at the bottom of my screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me worked installing open cv: pip install opencv-python

(https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

showing recommendation to install openCV
[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3):

Solved : Had to change to the directory it was in

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir (r'C:\******')
>>>button7location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('calc7key.png')
```